# log4j extras in OSGi environment

Tags: log4j, osgi

I want to use the log4j-extras-1.1.jar in OSGi environment (Fuse Fabric 7.1.0.fuse-047)
so that I can use archive feature of `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`

What are simplest steps to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't easily be done, and you actually don't need it. The used Pax-Logging provides a ZippedRollingFile appender out-of-the-box:

```
org.apache.log4j.zip. ZipRollingFileAppender
```